# Problem encountered while using PrintWriter in Java

Tags: java, servlets

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
  }
```

Does Fine
But if instead of "Hello World", if  a large String(String object with huge chunk of data ) is used, then nothing gets printed in the browser , in fact, no exception or error is thrown either.
Did any one encounter such a scenario?

Comment: Describe the unexpected behavior.

Comment: it doesn't show anything on browser

Comment: @abson is your "huge" string in html format?

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source*. Is it empty as well? If not, is it an gigantic HTML `<table>`? If so, try a better browser. MSIE can't handle large tables well.

Comment: Would be cool if you could tell us what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrintWriters don't throw exceptions. Use `checkError()` to test whether something went wrong (unfortunately it doesn't tell you what went wrong).

Write directly into the output stream (`response.getOutputStream()`) and catch exceptions to get more details.